Format problem when signing and verifying messages using Safe Wallet
I'm trying to validate signatures created by a Safe wallet using ISignatureValidator.isValidSignature. However, the validation fails with the error GS026. Below is the code I am using to generate and validate the signature.
Code
Signing the Message
I am using the following code to generate a signature with a Safe wallet:
import { ethers } from "ethers";
import EthSafeMessage from "@safe-global/protocol-kit/dist/src/utils/messages/SafeMessage";
import { SigningMethod } from "@safe-global/protocol-kit/dist/src/types/signing";

// Prepare the message
const channelId = "0x...";
const timestamp = Date.now();
const initialMessage: Uint8Array = messageToSignForChannelUpdate(channelId, 0, timestamp, [], []);
const messageHex = ethers.utils.hexlify(initialMessage);

// Sign the message using Safe wallet
const ethSafeMessage = await safe.signMessage(
  new EthSafeMessage(messageHex),
  SigningMethod.ETH_SIGN,
  safeWalletAddress
);

// Get the encoded signature
const userSignature = ethSafeMessage.encodedSignatures();

Validating the Signature
I am using the following code to validate the signature on-chain using ISignatureValidator.isValidSignature:
import { ethers } from "ethers";

const messageHash = ethers.utils.keccak256(initialMessage);
const ethSignedMessageHash = ethers.utils.hashMessage(messageHash);

const expectedSigner = safeWalletAddress.toLowerCase();
const iSignatureValidator = ISignatureValidator__factory.connect(expectedSigner, provider);

let isSignatureValid: boolean;

try {
  const result = await iSignatureValidator.isValidSignature(ethSignedMessageHash, userSignature);
  isSignatureValid = result === "0x1626ba7e"; // ERC1271_MAGICVALUE
} catch (error) {
  console.error("Failed to validate signature", error);
  isSignatureValid = false;
}

if (!isSignatureValid) {
  throw new Error("Invalid user signature");
}

Error
I receive the following error when trying to validate the signature:
[Nest] ERROR [OpenchannelService] failed to validate signature
[Nest] ERROR [OpenchannelService] Error: execution reverted: "GS026" (action="call", data="0x08c379a...", reason="GS026", transaction={ ... }, invocation=null, revert={ "args": [ "GS026" ], "name": "Error", "signature": "Error(string)" }, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=6.13.2)

Environment

Ethers.js Version: 6.13.2
Safe SDK Version: 4.0.3
Solidity Version: 0.8.x

Question
How can I correctly validate a signature created by a Safe wallet using ISignatureValidator.isValidSignature? Am I missing something in the message signing or validation process?

The issue arises from the subtleties in handling the magic values and the message/hashes posted to the API. Here's a detailed test case illustrating the correct approach: Originally i confused the two possible magic values and the encoding of the input/messageHash
import { ConfigService } from "@nestjs/config";
import { ethers } from "ethers";
import { SafeFactoryConfigProvider } from "@modules/blockchain/safe-factory-config.provider";
import Safe, { SafeFactory, SigningMethod } from "@safe-global/protocol-kit";
import * as dotenv from "dotenv";
import {
  ERC1271_MAGICVALUE,
  ERC1271_MAGICVALUE_BYTES
} from "@modules/common/constants";
import {
  CompatibilityFallbackHandler__factory,
  IErc1271Validator__factory,
  ISignatureValidator__factory
} from "@contracts/bindings";

dotenv.config();

describe("Safe Wallet", () => {
  let provider: ethers.JsonRpcProvider;
  let owner1: ethers.Wallet;
  let safe: Safe;
  let safeAddress: string;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    const configService = new ConfigService();
    const safeFactoryConfigProvider = new SafeFactoryConfigProvider(configService);

    provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider(configService.getOrThrow<string>("RPC_URL"));
    owner1 = new ethers.Wallet(configService.getOrThrow<string>("WALLET_PRIVATE_KEY"), provider);
    const owner2 = ethers.Wallet.createRandom().connect(provider);

    const balance = await provider.getBalance(owner1.address);
    if (balance === 0n) throw new Error(`Owner1 (${owner1.address}) has zero balance.`);

    const safeFactory = await SafeFactory.init(safeFactoryConfigProvider.getSafeFactoryConfig());
    const config = { owners: [owner1.address, owner2.address], threshold: 1 };
    safe = await safeFactory.deploySafe({ safeAccountConfig: config });
    safeAddress = await safe.getAddress();
  });

  it("should sign and validate a 'Hello world' message using EIP-1271", async () => {
    const message = "Hello world";
    const safeMessage = safe.createMessage(message);
    const hash = ethers.hashMessage(message);
    const ethSafeMessage = await safe.signMessage(safeMessage, SigningMethod.ETH_SIGN, safeAddress);
    const userSignature = ethSafeMessage.encodedSignatures();

    const isValid = await safe.isValidSignature(hash, userSignature);
    expect(isValid).toBe(true);
  });

  it("should validate a 'Hello world' message using EIP-1271 with different interfaces", async () => {
    const message = "Hello world";
    const hash = ethers.hashMessage(message);
    const ethSignedMessageHash = ethers.hashMessage(hash);
    const ethSafeMessage = await safe.signMessage(safe.createMessage(message), SigningMethod.ETH_SIGN, safeAddress);
    const userSignature = ethSafeMessage.encodedSignatures();

    const iSignatureValidator = ISignatureValidator__factory.connect(safeAddress, provider);
    expect(await iSignatureValidator.isValidSignature(ethSignedMessageHash, userSignature)).toBe("0x20c13b0b");

    const compatibilityFallbackHandler = CompatibilityFallbackHandler__factory.connect(safeAddress, provider);
    expect(await compatibilityFallbackHandler["isValidSignature(bytes32,bytes)"](hash, userSignature)).toBe("0x1626ba7e");

    expect(await compatibilityFallbackHandler["isValidSignature(bytes,bytes)"](hash, userSignature)).toBe("0x20c13b0b");

    const validator = IErc1271Validator__factory.connect(safeAddress, provider);
    expect(await validator.isValidSignature(hash, userSignature)).toBe("0x1626ba7e");
  });
});

Key Points:

Magic Values: Ensure you are using the correct magic values for validation.
Message Hashing: Correctly hash the message before signing and validating.
Sign and Validate: Ensure the signing and validation methods are using compatible formats and interfaces.

By carefully handling the magic values and message/hashes, you can successfully validate signatures created by a Safe wallet using ISignatureValidator.isValidSignature.
